# drag imported object in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, drag, unityscript

I have basic knowledge of unity and cannot figure out how drag an imported object in unity with the first person controller.

```
#pragma strict

private var ray:Ray;
private var hit: RaycastHit;


function Start()

function Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {

        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray,hit))
        {

            if(hit.collider.tag =="draggable")
            {
                transform.position.x = hit.point.x;
                transform.position.y=hit.point.y;
            }
        }
    }
}

function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider) {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);

        print("Hit");
    }
```

This is the script I have so far which works on a object that has been created in unity. I have searched for answers but they were all for objects that were created in unity.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing? Basically the drag code should not differ for objects coming with Unity (cube, etc) or imported objects. Make sure that imported objects have a collider attached, otherwise the RayCast won't hit them.

Comment: I completely forgot I posted my problem on here, I was able to sort it out, my first person controller was not tagged as 'main camera'.Thank you for replying anyway.